# mysql 8 on redhat 6.8 new installation

Tags: mysql, linux

I am new to MYSQL.
I installed MYSQL 8 using root user with the following steps:
**sudo yum install MYSQL-community-server**
**sudo service MySQL start**

**sudo service

status** -> OK

but, when I try to connect to database:
MYSQL

i get the error :"
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
with or without password - does not work.
pls help

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods to login to a newly installed MySQL 8, I just mention the easiest and mostly used method. You can find other methods here in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html).

To be able to login, MySQL generates an initial random password the first time it boots up. Check the contents of the mysqld.log file for the password. The default location for generic linux is `/var/log/mysqld.log`:

```
cat /var/log/mysqld.log |grep password
```

There should be a line like "Mysql Temporary password : ....." or something like that. If it's a fresh installation, the contents of the log file should not be big so finding the line should be easy.

Use the password to login for the first time. Then change the password with the following command for `root@localhost` :

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root-password';
```

I highly recommend that you check the official documentation linked above to understand the process and how to secure your fresh mysql installation.